# JSoup - Incrementing through Tags / Arrays

Tags: java, jsoup

Using the JSoup framework, I'm trying to iterate through the div's below and extract the text within the each of the `<p>` tags into an array.  Because the list of `<div>`'s and `<p>`'s is infinitely long, a do / while loop or for-loop would be the preferred method obtaining the information in `<p>`.

I do not know how to iterate through the `<div>` tags below, because I'm not sure how to keep track of what `<p>` tags of which `<div>`'s I'm storing into the array.  Apologies if the answer is an obvious one, as I'm somewhat new to Java and programming in general.

Thank you so much for your help. Let me know if there's anything I can add that would be of assistance.

**Example HTML (assume repeats hundreds of times):**

```
      <div class="happy-div"> // want everything within this div to be in one array element
              <p>good text here.</p> 
              <p>More good Text here.</p>
              <p>Some good stuff here.</p> 
      </div> 
      <div class="sad-div"> // want everything within this div to be in a separate array element
              <p>Some unhappy text here.</p>
              <p>More unhappy Text here.</p>
              <p>Some unhappy stuff here.</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="depressed-div"> // everything within this div to be in a separate array element
              <p>Some melancholy text here.</p>
              <p>More melancholy Text here.</p>
              <p>Some melancholy stuff here.</p> 
      </div>
      .... repeats hundreds of times
```

**Pseudocode:**

```
String[] arrayOfP;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++)
{
    arrayOfP[i] = doc.select("All of the text in the <p> tags within the div we've incremented to")
    System.out.println(arrayOfP[i])
}
```

**Expected Outcome:**

When printing the contents of the String array element values, I would expect to see this:

```
arrayofP[1] Some good text here. More good Text Here. Some good stuff here.
arrayofP[2] Some unhappy text here. More unhappy Text Here. Some unhappy stuff here.
arrayofP[3] Some melancholy text here. More melancholy Text Here. Some melancholy stuff here.
....
```

Comment: Post the sample array values.

Comment: I clarified the 'expected outcome' area.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashMap` to store the list of `P` elements for each `div`.
Each key of your map could be an id that you can give to your div, and the value is the list of `P` elements.

Ex:

```
<div id="id_1" class="happy-div">
    <p>good text here.</p> 
    <p>More good Text here.</p>
    <p>Some good stuff here.</p> 
</div> 

Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Elements divs = doc.select("div");
for (Element div : divs ) {
    List<String> pList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Elements pElements = div.select("p");
    for (Element pElement : pElements) {
        pList.add(pElement.text());
    }
    data.put(div.attr("id"), pLists);
}
for (List<String> pList : data.values()) {
    System.out.println(pList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this solution later on today and let you know what turns up.

Comment: Would I have to modify the HTML with the div id's? Unfortunately, I'm scraping this content from another website, so I can't really modify the HTML that's on the website?

Comment: Can you consider classes _(happy-div, sad-div, depressed-div)_ as unique for each of your divs? if so, you can use them instead of ids, even if it isn't an ideal solution.